# How do I remove SEGFAULT here?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I created a function to print the contents of a file:

```
void readFile(char* filename)
{
int c ; 
file = fopen(filename, "r");    
printf("The contents of the file are:\n");
while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
{
    printf("%c", c);
}   
return;
```

}

where `file` is a global variable. GDB gives output as follows:

```
_IO_getc (fp=0x0) at getc.c:39
39  getc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  _IO_getc (fp=0x0) at getc.c:39
#1  0x000000000040075e in readFile ()
#2  0x00000000004006d4 in main ()
```

However, the file is present and I get the SEGFAULT *after* printing the contents of the file. It *might* be because the buffer here (c) is small but I am not sure. Also, I don't know how do I fix this even if that were the case. Can anyone suggest how do I proceed?

**EDIT**
I call the readFile function only once. Here is my calling function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
char * filename;

filename = argv[1];
readFile(filename);
printf("File Handler: %ld", (long)file);

fclose(file);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't using `fopen` opens the file?

Comment: Use the `bt` command in GDB to print a backtrace. Then use the `up` command to walk up the call stack until you hit your code.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the typo. Fixed it.

Comment: If `fopen` fails, it will return `NULL`. You need to check for that.

Comment: You see it. Try to printf your filename before opening the zero pointer. Because it looks like You pass nothing to Your function.

Comment: If it prints the contents of the file before crashing, what makes you think the crash is inside this function?

Comment: Does it still SEGFAULT if you `fclose` the file?

Comment: @Adam - Please see the edited GDB backtrace. That's what makes me think that the SEGFAULT is in the function.

Comment: Your function runs fine in my system. so the problem may be in the file or outside the function.

Comment: Are you calling `readFile` multiple times? If so then please show the code *calling* the function.

Comment: And a small tip: compile your source file with the `-g` flag to gcc, it will add debug information (line numbers, pointers to source, etc).

Comment: The GDB trace shows `fp=0x0` which implies that the file pointer passed to (f)getc is NULL. Since you say it prints the file, that suggests to me that you're calling `readFile` multiple times. The first time succeeds, but a subsequent time fails to open the file.

Comment: You should check if `file` is NULL before you do anything with the file pointer. For example, print an error message and exit.

Comment: @Adam - I call the function only once. Please see the edit.

Comment: Add the check for NULL anyway. You're not doing anything obviously wrong, so whatever the error is will come from an unexpected place. The way to find such errors is to add error checking and asserts.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing in a filename that doesn't exist or for some other reason cannot be opened. Get rid of the segfault by checking for errors (you'll need to `#include <errno.h> and <string.h>` too for this:

```
void readFile(char* filename)
{
  int c ; 
  file = fopen(filename, "r");    
  if (file == NULL) {
     printf("Cannot open file '%s' : %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
     return;
  }
  printf("The contents of the file are:\n");
  while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
  {
      printf("%c", c);
  }   
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your file is `NULL` and you are still trying to read it.

I simulated this behaviour (SEG fault) when I deleted this file.

If file exists then your code works fine.

Check what path you are passing.. If you are using single `\` try with `\\` and see if this works. First `\` will work as escape sequence and final path will be send as `D:\temp\use.dat` to `fopen`.

```
readFile("D:\\temp\\user.dat");
```

Comment: If the file doesn't exist how can does `gcc` print its contents for me?

Comment: You have printed statement "The contents of the file are" .. and not actual contents of the file..right?

Comment: I printed the actual contents of file after that.

Comment: I ran your updated code and provided argument as D:\\temp\\user.dat.. worked perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything with a file, you must ensure that you opened it successfully. This is done by checking that the file pointer received by calling `fopen` is not `NULL`.

Once you do this, you read using whatever function you choose until it returns a value that indicates failure to read — a `NULL` pointer for `fgets`, `0` or `EOF` for `fscanf`, or `EOF` for `fgetc`.

In any case, you challenge these return values in two ways. The first way is to check for read errors using `ferror`. The other way is to check whether the end of the file was reached using `feof`.

A complete program that should work, based upon your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { OPEN_ERROR = 1, READ_ERROR };
enum { PARAM_EXIT = 1, OPEN_EXIT, READ_EXIT };

FILE *file = NULL;

int readFile(char* filename)
{
    int c;

    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return OPEN_ERROR;

    printf("The contents of file '%s' are:\n", filename);
    while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
        printf("%c", c);

    /*
     * fgetc returns EOF on end of file and when an error occurs.
     * feof is used to determine whether the end of the file was reached.
     * Otherwise, we encountered a read error.
     */
    if (feof(file))
        c = 0;
    else
        c = READ_ERROR;

    return c;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status = 0;

    if (argc == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        return PARAM_ERROR;
    }

    /* Check that <program ""> wasn't used... */
    if (argv[1][0] == '\0') {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: empty filename detected, exiting. . .\n");
        return PARAM_ERROR;
    }

    switch (readFile(argv[1])) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case OPEN_ERROR:
        fprintf(stderr, "error: file open failed - %s\n", strerror(errno));
        status = OPEN_EXIT;
        break;
    case READ_ERROR:
        fprintf(stderr, "error: file read failed - %s\n", strerror(errno));
        status = READ_EXIT;
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "error: unknown error occurred, aborting...\n");
        abort();
    }

    if (file != NULL)
        fclose(file);

    return status;
}
```

Of course, normally you would close the file in the same function in which it was opened (e.g. something like `filep = openFile(...); readFile(filep); fclose(filep);`, except error handling would be used of course).

Answer (score -1):

**I am completely changing my answer**

Actually, the file that I was reading was open in gedit (which might explain why I was getting "`NULL`" even after printing the file contents. I closed the file and removed my `NULL` comparison code and it works perfectly fine.

<strike>Ok, from everybody's comments I got to know that you basically get a `SEGFAULT` when you read the contents of file that has `NULL` contents. I just made a simple fix in my while loop:</strike>

```
while((c != EOF))
{
printf("%c", c);
c = fgetc(file);
if(c == NULL)
    break;
}
```

Problemo solved! (Although, the compiler gives me a warning of "comparison between pointer and integer".)

Comment: there is no such thing as a file with `NULL` contents. A file can be empty, but that does not make it `NULL`. Again, make sure fopen didn't return NULL.

Comment: I did make sure. I made an edit into the code as suggested by @nos but the actual file contents get printed (and not `"Cannot open file '%s' : %s\n"`). I don't know why my solution works though. :(

Comment: +1 for your comment, that made me look more into the code even though my problem was "solved".